# Global variables in importing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have the following code:
`one.py`

```
import two as t 

t.test1()

t.test2()
```

`two.py`

```
class test_class():
    def __init__(self,arg):
        print("created obj name is {}".format(arg))
        self.name = arg

non_global ="initial global"

obj = test_class("test name")



def test1():
    print("\t in test 1")
    print (obj.name)
    global non_global # wont work without global keyword, value still refers to "initial value"
    print(non_global) # initial value
    obj.name = "changed"
    #non_global = "changed global"


def test2():
    print("\tin test 2")
    print(obj.name)
    print(non_global)
```

The result is:

```
created obj name is test name
         in test 1
test name
initial global
        in test 2
changed
changed global
```

if I change in `test1()` to:

```
def test1():
    print("\t in test 1")
    print (obj.name)
    #global non_global # wont work without global keyword, value still refers to "initial value"
    print(non_global) # initial value
    obj.name = "changed"
    non_global = "changed global"
```

I get the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'non_global' referenced before assignment` on the print line.

If I comment `non_global = "changed global"` the error goes away.

my questions is:

Why is this happening for `non_global` and not for `obj`? I am on `python 3.5`

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question and then re-ask it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357636/why-no-need-for-global-for-class-object-when-importing

Comment: An assignment to `obj.name` isn't an assignment to `obj`. Only an assignment to `obj` would be grounds for the compiler to generate an `obj` local variable.

Comment: @AndyG I didnt think the format of that was good enough, was too hasty in asking that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is basically that `non_global` is a variable assignment and `obj.name` is an attribute assignment.

A variable assignment within a function makes that variable a local variable and due to that Python won't look it up anywhere other than local scope, hence `print(non_global)` fails because it wasn't defined yet in that scope. This works with `global` statement because by using `global` you're telling Python to not consider it a local variable and hence its value can be fetched from global scope.

The decision of whether a variable is going to a local is taken when a function body is parsed, hence when to try to use it before the actual declaration you will get an error at runtime.

`obj.name` on the other hand basically searches for `obj` using simple [LEGB lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) and then sets `name` attribute with the specified value.

Similarly you can also update global mutable datastructues(list, dict etc) within a function body without using `global`.

Apart from `=`, augmented assignments like `*=`, `+=` also make a variable a local variable.

```
a = []

def func1():
    a += ['foo']

def func2():
    a.extend(['bar'])

def func3():
    a[0] += 'spam'


func1()  # Fails with UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

func2()  # works fine

func3()  # Also works fine because a[0] is not a variable. 
         # We are telling Python to look for `a` and fetch its 0th item
         # and concatenate 'spam' to it.

print(a) # prints ['barspam']
```

---

The bytecode disassemble can also help you in pointing out the differences:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(func1)
 45           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')  # Load a local variable name foo
              6 BUILD_LIST               1
              9 INPLACE_ADD
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (a)      # Store local variable named foo
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(func2)
 48           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)      # Load from global scope
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (extend)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('bar')
              9 BUILD_LIST               1
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             15 POP_TOP
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(func3)
 51           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)      # Load from global scope
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 DUP_TOPX                 2
              9 BINARY_SUBSCR
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 ('spam')
             13 INPLACE_ADD
             14 ROT_THREE
             15 STORE_SUBSCR
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE

# Names of local variables or arguments of each function obtained through its code object
>>> func1.__code__.co_varnames
('a',)
>>> func2.__code__.co_varnames
()
>>> func3.__code__.co_varnames
()
```

---

Related: [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Comment: if the last line of `test1()` is `non_global = "changed global"` i get the error. I dont understand why a line after the print statement causes an issue. If that line is commented everything is good. A line after the print statement is as good as a comment anyway right?

Comment: @pyjg Check paragraph 3.

Comment: Thank you, so the function body is parsed and then executed line by line? I dont quite understand the flow

Comment: @pyjg Parsing of a module or a function results in a bytecode and that byte code contains instructions to be used at runtime. The instruction under `func1` are to load `a` from local scope(`LOAD_FAST`) but that variable doesn't exists that time and hence we get `UnboundLocalError `.

Comment: looking at the link you provided and its making more sense now. Thank you!